# I have written a php code which executes a python prog..it is running on a lampp server how do i get the python libraries working?

Tags: python, lamp

I am using ubuntu 11.10. I want to enable the execution of python libraries on my lampp server. I have written a php code that does shell_exec() to run a python script,but the libraries used in the python script are not working. How do I enable it on lampp?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer your question due to a lack of details. However, have you using mod_python instead of calling through php?

http://www.modpython.org/